# Javascript cycling through numbers to appear in document

Tags: javascript, timing, intervals

I'm trying to cycle through 10 numbers (1 - 9) on the screen every second. Sort of like the green matrix code from the movie..

here is my code, I cant for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've tried many other things but this seems the most correct to me:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function numberScroll(){

n = setInterval("Math.floor(Math.random()*11",100);
setInterval("document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=n",100);

}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="numberScroll()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ***never*** pass a string to setInterval/setTimeout.

Use a function instead:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = n;
}, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/Tmqbk/

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)},100);
```

Comment: I'm always looking to learn something new, so an explanation with the down vote would have been appreciated.

Comment: Probably for making it a one-liner without any text besides the code